# CommandBuilder and SqlTransaction to insert/update a row

Tags: sqlconnection, sqlcommandbuilder, sqltransaction

I can get this to work, but I feel as though I'm not doing it properly.

The first time this runs, it works as intended, and a new row is inserted where "thisField" contains "doesntExist"

However, if I run it a subsequent time, I get a run-time error that I can't insert a duplicate key as it violate the primary key "thisField".

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{           
    using(var sqlConn = new SqlConnection(connString) )
    {
        sqlConn.Open();
        var dt = new DataTable();

        var sqlda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM table WHERE thisField ='doesntExist'", sqlConn);
        sqlda.Fill(dt);

        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

        dr["thisField"] = "doesntExist"; //Primary key

        dt.Rows.Add(dr);

        //dt.AcceptChanges(); //I thought this may fix the problem. It didn't.

        var sqlTrans = sqlConn.BeginTransaction();

        try
        {
            sqlda.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM table WITH (HOLDLOCK, ROWLOCK) WHERE thisField = 'doesntExist'", sqlConn, sqlTrans);

            SqlCommandBuilder sqlCb = new SqlCommandBuilder(sqlda);

            sqlda.InsertCommand = sqlCb.GetInsertCommand();
            sqlda.InsertCommand.Transaction = sqlTrans;

            sqlda.DeleteCommand = sqlCb.GetDeleteCommand();
            sqlda.DeleteCommand.Transaction = sqlTrans;

            sqlda.UpdateCommand = sqlCb.GetUpdateCommand();
            sqlda.UpdateCommand.Transaction = sqlTrans;

            sqlda.Update(dt);

            sqlTrans.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

Even when I can get that working through trial and error of moving AcceptChanges around, or encapsulating changes within Begin/EndEdit, then I begin to experience a "Concurrency violation" in which it won't update the changes, but rather tell me it failed to update 0 of 1 affected rows.

Is there something crazy obvious I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to over come my problems by manually deleting the row(s) after filling the datatable.  I'm unable to use `dt.Clear()`, as doing so still results in an exception due to trying to insert a record with a duplicate primary key.

```
sqladapter.Fill(dt);

foreach( DataRow d in dt.Rows )
    d.Delete();

DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

dr.BeginEdit();
//update dr
dr.EndEdit();

dt.Rows.Add(dr);
```

The above will successfully let me insert a new row, and update a pre-existing row. Removing the foreach will generate the "Cannot insert duplicate key in object," so I feel I've at least found *a* solution; although, I feel as though it's not *the* solution.

Hope this helps someone.